# How to show woocommerce login / registration form in modal

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-login-form, media-modal

I have developed E-commerce Website using Woocommerce Plugin.

I would like to show the login/registration form in modal. Is there any way to automatically show the login/registration form when the user is not yet logged in.

Here's the scenario:

Shop loads -> Check if the user is already loggedin. If yes, shop page will show. If not, login/registration will popup.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to mix PHP + Javascript to do that. PHP to check if user is logged in and load login/register form, and javascript to show it in the modal way. There is a plugin that seems to do that, maybe you can get some results with it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplemodal-login/

Comment: this is too general to be of any use

Comment: Woot, this one is dated huh? I don't disagree with you, but the question itself is a lot general. She don't ask for something specific, but for a general solution for her problem. If she have asked for something more specific like "How to popup this form I've made in a lightbox only when the user is not logged in?", the answer would be much more complete. But the way she asked seemed much more as if she was looking for an option in the WooCommerce or WordPress itself. The own rate of the question point this way.

Comment: if it is a question which is too general, than there is no reason to give it an answer. You have enough rep to comment on such questions. In any case link only answers are a no-no unless they explicitly answer the question without any need of further integration/customization..... and that spcific plugin is not supported any more

Comment: The link did answer the question. The plugin may not be supported today (You're poking people in a almost 2 years question) but by the reviews there, it's still working.

Comment: can't underrstand how to explain it better. plugins will always go stale, therefor linking to a plugin is almost never an answer. Unsupported plugin is always suspect of security issues even if it seems to work